# When we are making a project in a group, how can we say that sentence?

Tags: formality

Hello I'm preparing a CV in English. What is the formal way of saying I'm in an project? This sentences below are valid or not ? Thanks.

1. I'm included to a project.
2. I have been enrolled to a project.
3. Something else.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that this site is not a proofreading service, though we can help you if you identify a specific question about grammar or usage. Why do *you* think one or the other might be correct? What are some examples you have seen in other CVs posted online or in CV writing guides?  I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for a better understand of how this site operates and what our standards are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say " I have been participating in a project", from the word [participate](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=participate); take part.

synonyms:   take part in, engage in, join in, get involved in, share in, play a part/role in, be a participant in, partake in, have a hand in, be associated with.

Comment: Note that this usage usually implies a *voluntary* participation in the project. If instead you have been directed to contribute to the project as part of your job, you'd be more likely to use something like "I am assigned to a project."

Answer (score 0):

You can say *I'm a member of a team working on a project.*